# Vercel Pipeline Build Failed to be displayed/notified in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vercel

Got a [Vercel build/deploy Pipeline ][1] which is showcased in the image attached.

- Notice the 'Build Failed'

The Vercel Pipeline is triggered by a [Azure DevOps Pipeline][2]

- Notice all runs are green and successful

Would it be possible to map the Failed Deployments in Vercel to Azure DevOps, and notify to the Team whenever Vercel throws and error, if so, could anyone expand on this topic?

If questions or additional questions let me know.
Br
CHRX
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gklP.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWmpe.png

Comment: Did you find something for this, looking for same solution.